# EntityColumnNotFound: No entity column "joinDate" was found

Tags: angular, postgresql, typeorm

I need to update the *User* entity using typeorm. *User* has extra calculated column `joinDate` as below:

```
export default class USAppUser extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("uuid")
  id: string;

  joinDate: number;

  @AfterLoad()
  getJoinDate() {
    this.joinDate = new Date(this.created_at).getTime();
  }
}
```

Now, I update `User` entity as below:

```
async updateUser(userId, url) {
  const dbUser = await User.findOne(userId);

  if (!dbUser) {
    throw new UserInputError("User doesn't exist.");
  }
  dbUser.avatar = url + "?time=" + super.getTimeStamp();

  // delete dbUser.joinDate; // ** Need to do this to update without errors **

  await User.update(userId, { ...dbUser });

  return dbUser.avatar;
}
```

Typeorm throws exception

> EntityColumnNotFound:No entity column "joinDate" was found.

As a workaround I am using `delete dbUser.joinDate` to remove property before update.
But I am sure there is a better way to do this. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow `update` function wasn't working. Tried `save` function and it worked without any changes.

```
dbUser.avatar = url + "?time=" + super.getTimeStamp();
await User.save(dbUser); //save works
```

Answer (score 0):

Change getJoinDate to

```
@AfterLoad()
getJoinDate() {
    return new Date(this.created_at).getTime();
}
```

Remove the joinDate property from the entity and just call getJoinDate() wherever joinDate was referenced.

EDIT

This is another way to do it.

```
export class JoinDateUSAppUser { 
    constructor(private user: USAppUser) {}

    joinDate: number;
    getJoinDate() {
        this.joinDate = new Date(this.user.created_at).getTime();
    }
}
```

This way you would have to create a separate variable to access joinDate.

Comment: Is this the only workaround? Coz I have other similar props which depend on values from data

Comment: The only other way I can think of involves creating a new class that derives from USAppUser and adding joinDate there. But then you might need to make sure to cast back to USAppUser before the update.

Comment: @User3250 actually I just thought of another way, one second

Comment: Fixed it using save()